# Php get keys from associative array

Tags: php, laravel

How could I get only the entire first row from an array. (I use Laravel)

For example when I say:

```
$request-all();
```

I receive:

```
array:2 [
  "email" => "james@hotmail.com"
  "password" => "adms|Wh"
]
```

I want to receive:

```
email
password
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_keys

Comment: Sounds like you want the keys of that associative array? (https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach ($keys as $key){
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Or simply foreach($array as $key => $value) { echo $key }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to get all the keys out of an associative array.

```
$array = array("email"=>"james@hotmail.com", "password"=>"adms|Wh");
```

Get keys from $array array

```
 print_r(array_keys($array));
```

You can also use the PHP [foreach loop](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-loops.php) to find or display all the keys, like this:

Loop through $array array

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
}
```